# Olimexino (32u4): power down

Tags: power

I want to power down my Olimexino as much as possible and only wakeup on a pin-change interrupt. I removed the 3.3V/5V jumper (so the processor does not get power) and 3µA were displayed, so the voltage regulator is really a low power variant. What I have done:

```
#include <avr/power.h>

power_all_disable();
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
sleep_enable();
sleep_cpu();
```

This resulted in still using 220µA. Now I disable the ADC, too:

```
ADCSRA = 0;
```

which reduces it to 100µA. I've tried to disable further ADC-stuff using

```
ACSR = 0;
ADMUX = 0;
```

and tried to disable (?) the Watchdog Timer using

```
WDTCSR = 1 << WDP3;
```

but without any further improvements. The datasheet for the 32u4 suggests to disable the Brown-Out-Detector, too, but I don't seem to be able to do that using code, but only by setting some fuses which is not possible directly using the Arduino IDE. Any further ideas?

Comment: Did you use the `PRRx` registers? Did you disable JTAG? Why can't you use ISP?

Comment: PRRx registers are set using `power_all_disable()`. JTAG? I don't use ISP, because that doesn't work with the Arduino IDE.

Comment: ISP works fine with the Arduino IDE. It just doesn't work with the USB connection. Besides, you wouldn't set the fuse through the IDE regardless.

Comment: The timing for setting the registers to disable the brown-out-detection is pretty strict. You'll have to set the registers right before `sleep_cpu()`

Comment: Gerben, what registers to set for the 32u4?